# Click on Toast Notification Launch new instance of app when application already started? - Migration from 81. app to UWP

Tags: notifications, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have migrated my application from 8.1 to Win 10 UWP app. When I click on Toast Notification and application is already running, the click launches the new instance of the app and goes back to loading the 1st page of the app.

Is there any reason for this? I dnt see any thing wrong in the codebase.

Comment: Does it really open a new window? It should call `OnLaunched` in your `App.xaml.cs`. The default code (of a new UWP project) neither opens a window nor navigates anywhere if the rootFrame already displays content. We'd need your code and some better description of the problem to be able to help you.

Comment: I have OnLaunchApplicationAsync in my app.xaml.cs and yes..the control goes to there in app.xaml.cs. Lets say that if I am at Page B and Page is the 1st page. When I click on notification, the same windows will start loading Page A inspite of me being on Page B. Which part of the codebase I should share for better idea?

Comment: Are you using Template10 or so? If so, please share your `OnStartAsync` and `OnLaunchApplicationAsync` so we can check where your `NavigationService.Navigate` is at. I bet it's in the latter function instead of the first one.

Comment: I am not using Template 10 but I am using Prism for navigation and sessions.And I override the below method from PrismApplication. protected override UIElement CreateShell(Frame rootFrame)
        {
            SplitViewPage shell = new SplitViewPage(rootFrame, NavigationService);
            return shell;
        }